# Setting Variable During Callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

The following jQuery code attempts to store a client's IP address in a global variable during the callback for an ajax GET request.

### Code

```
  var userip = null;
  $.ajax({
    url: "http://ipinfo.io",
    type: 'get',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    async: false,
    success: function(data) {
      userip = data.ip;
      console.log(userip); // prints unique ip address
    }
  }).done(console.log(userip)); // prints null
```

Knowing that GET requests are usually executed asynchronously (but requiring otherwise), I have marked `async: false` in the JSON spec. For added measure, I call `done()` to ensure the request has finished before continuing.

Nevertheless, printing `userip` returns null after the GET request but prints the unique client IP during the ajax success callback.

Any explanation would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The .done function expects a function to callback. The console.log is just being evaluated right away. If you change the parameter of the .done function to be same anonymous function definition that you're using for "success" I think it will work as expected.

Comment: You probably shouldnt use `async: false,`. Instead, look into using the callback correctly or [using deferred / returning a promise](http://joseoncode.com/2011/09/26/a-walkthrough-jquery-deferred-and-promise/)

Comment: @DelightedD0D That's absolutely correct and good advice. I'm fairly certain the OP is expecting to to be treated as if the request is occuring in block, i.e. if there was another line **after** the code shown, it would be executed after the request is complete. Is that correct, @JayDoe?

Comment: @Mic that's definitely correct! In which case, reading up via the URL posted by DelightedD0D, deferred/promises seem like the best solution I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.done() expects a callback. Try swapping out

```
console.log(userip)
```

with

```
function() { console.log(userip); }
```

Comment: This works but I don't quite understand why `async: false` is insufficient to postpone code following the ajax call until after success or failure? Simply executing `console.log(userip)` after the ajax call also returns null for example. Is this why one needs to use promises/deferred?

Comment: @JayDoe If you supply console.log(userip) as an argument, the javascript interpreter will execute it because it's a function *call*. Just like if you did, for example, console.log(myFunction())... myFunction would execute, and its *result* would be the argument passed into console.log. The async:false flag in Jquery can't change how the javascript interpreter will inherently evaluate the code.

Answer (score 0):

what you're doing is making the `console.log(userip)` execute immediately, and not after the request is completed. Which is why `userip` gets stored properly in the success handler. Think of `done` as what to do once the request is completed. It needs to execute an action (function). You're passing a statement (`console.log(userip)`) which actually returns `undefined`. So `done` doesn't do anything.

try this instead

```
}).done(function() {
    console.log(userip);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var userip = null;
  $.ajax({
  url: "http://ipinfo.io",
  type: 'get',
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  async: false,
  success: function (data) {
    userip = data.ip;
    console.log(userip); // prints unique ip address
  },
  complete: function () {
    console.log(userip); // prints unique ip address
  }
});
```